# Why vector in C++ doesn't resize automatically

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, factorial

I've a very long factorial program which needs to find factorial up to 100. It works well up to 33 factorial but not from 34. Can someone help in identifying the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>


using namespace std;

void bigFactorials(int n)
{
    vector<int> v;//If I specify the size as v(1000) it works fine but I don't 

    //want to specify the size beforehand.
    v.push_back(1);

    // Complete this function
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        int carry = 0, mul=0;
        for(auto j=v.rbegin();j!=v.rend();j++) {
            mul=i**j + carry;
            carry=mul/10;
            *j=mul%10;
        }

        if(carry)
            v.insert(v.begin(),carry);    
    }

    for(int i:v)
        cout<<i;
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin >> n;
    if( n>0 && n<101 )
        bigFactorials(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller: I don't think he's trying to store 34! in an `int`. It looks like he's trying to store it in a rudimentary BigInt implementation using a vector.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - Interesting. I thought he was trying to store all the factorials values from to in a range. NVM then

Comment: What is `mul = i**j + carry;` supposed to do?

Comment: @Bob__ dereference the iterator j and multiply by i?

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` don't do this, it's an internal header file. Its only purpose is to contain `using namespace std;`

Comment: Use `unsigned long` for `unsigned long carry = 0, mul=0;` you get an overflow by `i**j + carry`. And you need tong if you want to get to 100.

Comment: Note that if your calculation speed is your priority, you should stop calculating in terms of decimal digits and use binary. OK, printing the result in decimal will become a lot more work.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is when carry > 10, then you insert one integer value without splitting it into chars, it should be implemented as follows

```
if(carry)
{
    if (carry >= 10)
    {
        while (carry > 0)
        {
            v.insert(v.begin(),carry % 10); // put each char from carry into v
            carry = carry / 10;
        }
    }
    else
        v.insert (v.begin(),carry);
}
```

with this you can even keep `v` as `vector<char>` and for 50! we have 
30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000.

Comment: verified up to 99!

Comment: Thanks @rafix07 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely overflowing, when I print out the `carry` values that are added to the vector:

```
1
5
4
3
3
3
4
6
8
13
20
35
64
121
243
510
1124
2585
6204
15511
40329
108888
304888
884176
2652528
8222838
26313083
86833176
-134263930
-134263930-639604140847618609643520000000
```

I switched to `long long` for the vector and for `carry` and `mul` and was able to get the correct answer for 34!, but 99! still overflows.  Seems you need to further reduce the numbers you are adding to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your `carry` in decimal digits and insert in-front of your *BigInt*.

```
while (carry)
{
    v.insert(v.begin(), carry % 10);
    carry /= 10;
}
```

Here the whole function:

```
void bigFactorials(int n) {
    vector<int> v;//If I specify the size as v(1000) it works fine but I don't 
    //want to specify the size beforehand.
    v.push_back(1);

    // Complete this function
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int carry = 0, mul = 0;
        for (auto j = v.rbegin(); j != v.rend(); j++)
        {
            mul = i * *j + carry;
            carry = mul / 10;
            *j = mul % 10;
        }

        while (carry)
        {
            v.insert(v.begin(), carry % 10);
            carry /= 10;
        }
    }

    for (int i : v)
        cout << i;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb513677599b3e3b)</kbd>